# Multiple SELECT into statements with creating tables SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I have a large table with all of the state and county information in America in one place.

table structure is

```
    fullCode   countyName   stateName   stateCode
1   01001        nowhere      AL          01
2   01003        somewhere    AL          01
3   02100        other        AK          02
```

The state code is always identified by the first two numbers in the `fullCode` column.  These are unique to each state so no state will have more than one set of preceding two numbers.  The last three numbers on the countyCode.

I used the query below to create a table with all of the states

```
select distinct stateName, statecode
into tblStates
from tblCounties
```

I'm curious how one could create a table for each state's counties in one fell swoop (if possible).  Something like

```
select distinct  fullCode, countyName
into tblAlabamaCounties
from tblCounties
where stateName='AL'
```

but for every state.  Then of course I'd have to deal with all the PK/FK issues.  Just wondering the methods that might be employed to do something like this.

EDIT: if this is a design error, how else can I associate the names of a county that are in a particular state?  I could leave everything in one big table, but that seems like poor design, thoughts?

Comment: Hm why would you create a table per state? This looks like a design error to me.

Comment: There's a state table for all of the states in America.  I then want every county in America to be associated with its state.

Comment: The only way to do what you want is to use dynamic SQL, and it's not a great idea to use Dynamic SQL in DDL scripts.  Dynamic SQL is dangerous, and DDL isn't something to play around with.

Comment: As to your design question, don't think about how many rows a table will have as an evaluative measure of good/bad design.  Does everything in the table represent the same kind of entity/object/data?  Are there appropriate keys and constraints?

Comment: Yes, everything in the table represents the same type of data.  There will be no variance between one state and the other, so logically I could keep my one table with all of the relevant info in there, keys and everything.  However, for data integrity issues I thought it best to set up a table containing all 50 states, and then  have a stateCounties table.  Would this not be advisable?

Comment: For future querying, I thought I'd tell you about a quirk that happens only in VA (and it was a direct result of Brown Vs Board of Education). In Virginia you are in a city or a county but never both. This means that you may need to be able to join a future  City table directly to state and not count on it coming from the county.

Comment: I was looking through the FIPS codes and I did see that Virginia was weird.  Awesome attention to detail @HLGEM

Comment: Well I live here so I know about the quirk but I actually learned about it a Constitutional History course. Had no thought back then of doing what I do now, but no knowledge is wasted. That little fact has come in handly for me in doing database work.

Comment: That is exactly why the aggregation of knowledge over time makes for a better, more informed citizen.  I try to tell people all the time that the 'useless' things you know will come in handy one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here would be a better design you might consider:

State Table:

```
STATE_ID
STATE_ABBREV
STATE_NAME
```

County Table:

```
COUNTY_ID
STATE_ID
COUNTY_NAME
```

Sample Data:

```
STATE_ID   STATE_ABBREV   STATE_NAME
01         AL             Alabama
02         AK             Alaska

COUNTY_ID  STATE_ID       COUNTY_NAME
001        01             Nowhere
003        01             Somewhere
100        02             Other
```

Your Primary Key for the state table would be the STATE_ID
Your Primary Key for the county table would be COUNTY_ID ---AND---- STATE_ID (COMBINED)

With this structure, you've got just 2 tables, with which you can easily reproduce your original "large" table, as well as the "full code" field.  Additionally, updating, querying, creating procs, functions, etc. is going to be a lot easier down the road based on this (much simpler / more normal) structure.

FWIW

Comment: Can you extol some of the virtues of the ease of updating?  I do like this streamlined design.

Comment: The biggest thing is cross-state queries I think.  Imagine someone wants to know all the counties in the country that start with `Ham`.  In your other design this involves `UNION` across 50 tables.

Comment: Yes -- JNK makes the main point for querying the data out.  Other considerations include how much work you want to have to put into table mods down the road (adding fields, etc.), playing nicely with others (will anyone be consuming your data besides you?), etc.  It's the subject of a few books I've seen.  :-)  You might enjoy the wikipedia entry on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.  (Not advocating it -- I'll assume they hit most of the major points...)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle, you could create a PL-SQL procedure where you create first of all the different tables, and then you only have to populate the data into the new tables recently create.
IF you use PL SQL procedure you could do it.

On the other hand you can create the different tables, and create a triggers before insert, and you will insert the data in the specific table before insert in your master table.

Sorry for my English I hope you can understand all and help you.